# Verifying transaction for Wordpress users by adding a custom data via update_user_meta?

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

The title may sound a bit complicated, but it's more simpler than it sounds..

I'm not sure if my logic is correct and optimal, but I couldn't think of other logical way.

I have logged in users that I want to mark as 'paid' users after the PayPal transaction, by updating their profile data using `update_user_meta`.

Basically, I'm trying to achieve this:

Step 1. Logged in user clicks on PayPal button to make a payment.

Step 2. After a payment, redirect to the Wordpress front end (hidden) form, where using `update_user_meta` add the `meta_key` 'confirmed' and set `meta_value` to 'yes'.

Make it so that the step 2 would execute in the background (automatically prepopulate the field value with "yes" and somehow hit enter). And then quickly redirect back to the user's profile page.

This is where the user will see the text: "confirmed: yes".

Knowing that the meta value now exist for that specific paid user, I could now unlock my premium features.

If meta_value for meta_key 'confirmed' is empty, the features will remain locked.

So my question is this:

1. Is my logic correct, or is there an easier way to do the transaction verification on Wordpress?
   Maybe tagging somehow with redirects? Paypal transaction > TAGGING PAGE > back to wordpress profile.
2. If my logic is correct, I already know how to add a new custom field in the user profile, so that the user could update, but I can't make that work on the front end.
3. How to execute the 'enter', on behalf of the user, so that he won't be needing to press "confirm" button after the transaction to update the user meta value.
   I need this, so that in case a user navigate or close the window and won't hit enter, the field won't be updated and the features won't be unlocked.

So I want that to be executed in the background without user needing to do anything.

I'm stuck. and need some advice and guidance from experienced coders.

**EDIT:**

The reason I decided to update user's meta data, is because of the easier content control using:

```
<?php if(get_the_author_meta('confirmed', $user->ID ) != ''): ?>
<strong><font color="green">Active!</font></strong> 
<?php else: ?>
<strong><font color="red">Inactive</font></strong> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

I figure out all three steps. My plan is working now:)

Thanks again to the commentators.

Comment: You shouldn't require form entry from the user. Whatever code confirms the PayPal transaction occurred, should trigger your `update_user_meta`. This might be an API capture or execute or DoExpressCheckoutPayment request, or it might be an IPN handler.

Comment: I agree, but I couldn't find any other way to connect/send data from PayPal to Wordpress, than the way I described. Btw, it's not a WooCommerce site (which has some plugins for this). It's a simple wordpress blog. Thanks for your insight though. Preston.

Comment: If you integrate PayPal Checkout with an API, there is no need to send and receive custom data. But if you must, there is a `custom` or `custom_id` parameter you can use, depending on how you integrate.

Comment: _“I couldn't find any other way to connect/send data from PayPal to Wordpress, than the way I described. Btw, it's not a WooCommerce site (which has some plugins for this)”_ - they ways to do this, exist independently from any specific system such as WooCommerce. You want to use a PayPal processing method/flow, that sends the data to a _callback URL_ within your system. Setting up an _endpoint_ for that, can be done using the WP Rest API functionality.

Comment: hey CBroe, thanks for your comment, I have already done step1 and step2, the only thing that's left is autosubmit. Which I'm trying to do using javascript or JQuery. Almost there. I'm doing this way (updating usermeta) because I could control content for each user, knowing that they are paid.